# how to combine two files in R?

Tags: r

I have several files in one dirctory:
 I list them all using:

```
  dir1<- list.files ("/data/", "*.txt", full.names = TRUE)
  Gh_12_kj.txt   
  kh_12_k.txt 
  Gh_13_kj.txt 
  kh_13_k.txt
```

I can read them one by one like this:

```
  for (i in seq_along(dir1)) {file =read.table(i) ……}
```

I want to combine all files with similar names but different numbers for example:

```
  Rbind Gh_12_kj.txt and Gh_13_kj.txt 
  Rbind s_13_f.txt and s_12_f.txt     and so on for all files in this dirctory
```

I guess we need `unique` but not sur how

Comment: Did you meant that it is not similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the 'dir1' object was created with the `full.names = TRUE` option from `list.files`, we can extract the file name with `basename` and `file_path_sans_ext` (from `tools`), then `split` the 'dir1' by the substring of 'files' i.e. only keeping the 'Ghkj_df', 'khf_df' etc. in 'Gh_12_kj_df.txt', 'kh_13_f_df.txt'), loop through the nested `list` elements with `lapply`, then loop again and read the files with `fread` and rbind them together with `rbindlist`.

```
library(data.table)
library(tools)
files <- file_path_sans_ext(basename(dir1))  
lapply(split(dir1, sub("^([^_]+)_\\d+_([^.]+)", "\\1\\2", files)), 
                          function(x) rbindlist(lapply(x, fread)))
```

Comment: @bicton  It is not clear about the error.  What do you get with `split(dir1, sub("_.*", "", files))`

Comment: @bicton  Based on your description in the post, these files are grouped togher and `rbind`ed and that is what the code does. i.e. `v1 <- c("Gh_12_kj.txt", "kh_12_k.txt", "Gh_13_kj.txt", "kh_13_k.txt"); split(v1, sub("_.*", "", v1))`

Comment: @bicton Yes, by using the `sub`, we are extracting only the `kh` or `Gh` part and so we get the `Gh` files all as a list element, likewise `kh` as another, then we loop through each of the nested elements, and read it with `fread`, `rbind` it together

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122127/discussion-between-akrun-and-bic-ton).